# Adding Splash Screen for vertical as well horizontal orientation in react native

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I am using [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) library to add a splash screen to my react native app.
As per the documentation, for Android we need to create a file called launch_screen.xml in app/src/main/res/layout with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

We can only have the orientation as either vertical or horizontal. I want to have a separate splash screen for vertical and horizontal. Above file allows only single RelativeLayout element.
Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For making a splash screen for landscape and portrait both. follow the below steps.

1.Create folder layout-land under res folder (this is for landscape).

2.In that folder, copy the launch_screen.xml file.

3.Change src resource portrait splash image to your landscape splash image

The appropriate file will be loaded at run-time automatically. no need to change in java code